# How to achieve fixed point scaling with transform control in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

As of now I could translate,rotate and scale with transform control in three.js .But recently in my three.js application I felt need of doing fixed point scaling for scaling an object.Even though I could achieve this by translating my object to origin than scaling it and translate back to original position but still I wanted to know if I could achieve this using transform control itself...Or is their any simple way to achieve this in three.js??please a little help.....just started to scratch surface of three.js :P

Comment: The control just sets the objects local sale. What do you mean by fixed point scale? You mean changing the object's position relative to the model, or move the whole object with its position too?

Comment: Ok..suppose we have a cube and I am scaling it in Y direction by dragging the scale control in positive Y direction..in default case transform control will scale the cube uniformly in both direction over Y-axis..What I want is when I drag the scale control in positive Y direction only the top side of the cube should be scaled and bottom of the cube should remain at the same position of world co-ordinate.i.e cube should be scaled along only +ve Y-axis which means only its height has changed but it is resting on same plane..